# I'm trying to get my form to populate with selected row so I can edit it

Tags: python, mysql, edit, pysimplegui

I'm using pysimplegui and have a search function which gives results in  a combobox.
Is there a way to click on a result and get it to populate the form with that result for editing.
I found the combo.bind and the combo.Widget.event_generate snippets in a stackoverflow post.
I've looked at the table section in pysimplegui.org but cant find what I'm looking for.I watched a few youtube videos but still no joy.
Is there a function or method I could use that I can't seem to find.
If someone could point me in the right direction, it would be  greatly appreciated, tks, Ian

```
combo = window['-SEARCH-']
combo.bind("<Return>","_Enter")

    while True:
        event, values = window.read() #values is a list in Python
        if event == '-SEARCH-' + '_Enter':
            surnames = retrieve_info(values,window)
            if len(surnames) > 0:
                window['-SEARCH-'].update(values=surnames, value=values['-SEARCH-'])
                combo.Widget.event_generate('<Button-1>')
```

and here's my retireve_info function

```
def retrieve_info(values,window):
    surnames = []
    if values['-SEARCH-'] == '':
        sg.PopupError('Please enter a valid surname')
    else:
        sSql = "SELECT SURNAME FROM PATIENT WHERE SURNAME like '%" + values['-SEARCH-'] + "%';"
        conn = create_connection(database)
        c = conn.cursor()
        c.execute(sSql)
        records = c.fetchall()
        for record in records:
            surnames.append(record[0])
        conn.commit()
        conn.close()
    return surnames
```

Heres a look at my app
Once I select a person, I'd looking for their info to populate the form so I can edit it before updating.

[image: Combobox with search results]

[image: The person who's details I'd like to populate the form with for editing]

Comment: I want is not a question, it suggests you want us to create code for you

Comment: Sorry, I'm trying is propably a more accurate description, I'll edit my wording now, tks

Answer (score 0):

There's something you missed - the GUI won't update immediately when you update the GUI widget.

Try to call `window.refresh()` after it and before you call `combo.Widget.event_generate('<Button-1>')`.

```py
import PySimpleGUI as sg

layout = [
    [sg.Combo([1,2,3,4,5], key='COMBO')],
    [sg.Button("Check")],
]
window = sg.Window('Title', layout)

while True:

    event,values = window.read()

    if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED:
        break
    elif event == 'Check':
        window['COMBO'].update(values=["A", "B", "C", "D", "E"])
        window.refresh()
        window['COMBO'].widget.event_generate('<Button-1>')

window.close()
```

Comment: Hi Jason, thanks for the tip. So if I want to see my udte I have to refresh the window first.